# Question about errata on page 171 of MetaFontBook

Tags: metafont

In [errata](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/errata/errata.tex) there is this errata for page 171 of MetaFontBook:

```
\bugonpage C171, line 16 from the bottom (06/18/02)

\tenpoint
\<loop>\is\<loop header>|:|\<loop text> {\tt endfor}
```

I have an edition of MetafontBook from 1986 (softcover) and from 2012 (hardcover). In both of them text on page 171 is the same as in output produced from `errata.tex`. Can anybody explain why this text is in errata if it seems not to correct anything?

Comment: Can you post a photograph of (at least the bottom half of) the page? That might help someone who doesn't have easy access to the book to catch something...

Comment: @ShreevatsaR ... or point to the line in [`mfbook.tex`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/mf/mfbook.tex).

Comment: @HenriMenke Well, I imagine `mfbook.tex` would have already incorporated the correction, so unless we're talking about a copy of `mfbook.tex` that's older than the correction, it's probably less helpful... but yeah still better than nothing I guess.

Comment: @egreg what do you mean by "misprint"? `mfbook.tex` was wrong? BTW, in `errata.tex` it is said that it lists corrections since the 6th printing of hardcover and 11th printing of softcover of MetaFont book. And in earlier errata (i.e., `errata.eleven`, `errata.ten` etc) there is no correction to this line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking closely in my 1986 and 1993 printings, the colon is in normal font and not in typewriter type as in the correction.

After looking in the historical archive of TUG, I found the distribution of 1998 and the line in `mfbook.tex` is

```
\<loop>\is\<loop header>:\<loop text>[endfor]
```